# Teshuvah: How to return or going back to one's true nature?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, commentaries, repentance-teshuvah

In the 5th bracha of the Amidah, we request from HaShem "our father" (אבינו), to return us (השיבנו) we mention three kinds of Teshuvah – 1. returning to HaShem, 2.returning to the Torah, and 3. returning in “complete” Teshuvah.

The first two I get, but the understanding of the last kind of Teshuvah I don't get.

Rabbi Mordechai Becher that this kind of Teshuvah is a return to the purity of one’s soul:

> אלוקי נשמה שנתת בי טהורה היא, אתה בראתה, אתה יצרתה, אתה נפחתה בי
>
> ... "My G-d, the soul you have given me is pure. You created it, You
> formed it, You breathed it into me ...":  Teshuvah, literally
> translated means “return.” We believe that the soul is intrinsically
> pure and began  its sojourn in this world in a state of purity.
> Mistakes and wrongdoings are departures from the  essential nature of
> the human soul. Therefore when a person has done something wrong, the
> process  of teshuvah is really that of going back to his or her true
> essence.

So Teshuvah doesn't only mean to return to HaShem and His Torah, but it also means to return, to return to the original state (its pristine core; to one's original nature) we were in.

But how does one achieve this? How does one return to his original self; what does this even mean? And how does this helps a person not to do a sin anymore in the future; wasn't it from this state of being that one sinned in the first place?

Comment: FWIW the version I use of that benediction doesn't have those three.

Comment: Mine too (edot mizrach) sl. different: 1. Return us Father, to your Torah  2. and draw us close to Your service, and 3. and bring us in complete teshuvah before you.  Barukh etc.

Comment: Maybe that's an answer right in the nusach? 1. What does it mean Hashiveinu etc. of course we're learning - i.e. go deeper in the Torah, to yeshuv hadaat and meshivat nafesh (also see my answer below re Shabbat),  and 2. Avoda - means prayer, avoda sh'b'lev, and then consequently..

Comment: The shla says that teshuva is hashava maalyeta, se the beautiful mashal in his chapter on teshuva, he quotes also the Sefer hayashar what compire teshuva to recovery from an illness

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Aseret_HaDibrot%2C_Yoma%2C_Ner_Mitzva.2.8?vhe=Shenei_Luchot_HaBrit,_based_on_Amsterdam,_1698_ed._Part_II&lang=bi

Answer (score 0):

> But how does one achieve this? How does one return to his original self; what does this even mean?

That explanation along "a return to one's pristine original self" as in the morning Berakha "Eloh' neshama" etc. could be helpful.

Here is another aspect to answer your main question, what is **Teshuvah Sheleima**? Just that - a **total return** up to the highest possible levels, close to God, that you can reach, as it says, "**and you shall return (W'SBTa) all the way up to (AD) H' your God**" (Deut. 30:2)

Basically through the aspect of **SBT/Shabbat (return and rest - same letters)**, the Moshe-Mashiach and the True Tzaddikim, and introspection - he can attain Teshuvah Sheleima.
This is [Likutei Moharan, Torah #79](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A8%22%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%98), בְּטַח בַּה' וַעֲשֵׂה-טוֹב, שְׁכָן-אֶרֶץ וּרְעֵה אֱמוּנָה (תְּהִלִּים ל"ז), see the whole lesson below in sequence. There are twenty occurences of **"תְּשׁוּבָה שְׁלֵמָה"**, highlighted here with asterisk (**). Some points from there:

- "Teshuvah" is the letters "Shabat - Hei." Through the Shabbat rest he can honestly see himself and make Teshuvah.
- When can a person see his lowliness? On Shabbat, as it says (Ex. 16), "See, for H' gave you HSBT/the Shabbat" [= letters Teshuvah].
- And Shabat is the letters Shin(=3) BaT - the three colors of the eye and the Bat/pupil - by Shabbat, one sees all the levels entirely: above him, below, and what he is.
- Who attained this? Who was "TOB" and complete? Who was "completely humble, than any man"? (Num. 12) Moshe (who is Mashiach - Zohar).
- Any True Tzaddik contains some revelation of Mashiach.  Now, each person must see to it to not hold up the Redemption.
- Shabat and **Teshuvah Sheleima** are interdependent, as ShaBaT/ShaBTa is the same spelling (Deut. 30): "W'ShBTa ad ([W - the aspect of the Tzaddik/Moshe, as is brought] - and you shall return - all the way up to) H' your God."

> And how does this helps a person not to do a sin anymore in the future; wasn't it from this state of being that one sinned in the first place?

Of course it will help. However it may not prevent sin entirely.
Even a complete Tzaddik can make a mistake. Moshe Rabbeinu himself erred in striking the rock. The origin of sin has to do with the Yetzer haRa, Atzath haNachash, the Erev Rav, etc. These are beyond the scope of this question but I think the above answers your main question.

> "לקוטי מוהר"ן -תורה עט"
> [לְשׁוֹן הַחֲבֵרִים]
> בְּטַח בַּה וַעֲשֵׂה טוֹב שְׁכָן אֶרֶץ וּרְעֵה אֱמוּנָה (תְּהִלִּים ל"
> [לְשׁוֹן הַחֲבֵרִים]
> בְּטַח בַּה' וַעֲשֵׂה טוֹב שְׁכָן אֶרֶץ וּרְעֵה אֱמוּנָה
> הִנֵּה הַכְּלָל שֶׁצָּרִיך כָּל אָדָם לִרְאוֹת שֶׁמִּצִּדּוֹ לא יִהְיֶה עִכּוּב מְשִׁיחָא
> דְּהַיְנוּ לַעֲשׂוֹת **תְּשׁוּבָה שְׁלֵמָה** וּלְתַקֵּן מַעֲשָׂיו
> וּבְכָל צַדִּיק וְצַדִּיק, מִי שֶׁהוּא צַדִּיק בֶּאֱמֶת, יֵשׁ בּוֹ הִתְגַּלּוּת מָשִׁיחַ
> וְאַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵין בּוֹ הִתְגַּלּוּת מָשִׁיחַ
> יֵשׁ בּוֹ מִדָּה שֶׁל מָשִׁיחַ, שֶׁהוּא בְּחִינַת משֶׁה
> כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתוּב בַּזוהַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ: 'מָשִׁיחַ דָּא משֶׁה', כְּמוֹ שֶׁאֲפָרֵשׁ
> כִּי משֶׁה מָסַר נַפְשׁוֹ בְּעַד יִשְׂרָאֵל
> כִּי יָדַע שִׁפְלוּתוֹ בֶּאֱמֶת, וְיָדַע חֲשִׁיבוּת וּגְדֻלּוֹת יִשְׂרָאֵל
> כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתוּב: "וְהָאִישׁ משֶׁה עָנָו מְאד מִכּל הָאָדָם"
> וּמֵחֲמַת זֶה מָסַר נַפְשׁוֹ וְחִיּוּתוֹ בַּעֲדָם
> לָכֵן מִי שֶׁהוּא צַדִּיק בֶּאֱמֶת
> וְיוֹדֵעַ שִׁפְלוּתוֹ, וְיַכִּיר חֲשִׁיבוּת יִשְׂרָאֵל
> יָכוֹל לִמְסֹר אֶת נַפְשׁוֹ בַּעֲדָם
> וְאֵימָתַי יָכוֹל לִרְאוֹת שִׁפְלוּתוֹ ? בְּשַׁבָּת
> "רְאוּ כִּי ה' נָתַן לָכֶם אֶת הַשַּׁבָּת"
> כִּי שַׁבָּ"ת הוּא שִׁי"ו בַּת
> 'שִׁי"ו', תְּלַת גְּוָנִין דְּעֵינָא, 'בַּ"ת' בַּת עַיִן
> וְעַל כֵּן בְּשַׁבָּת יָכוֹל לִרְאוֹת שִׁפְלוּתוֹ
> הַיְנוּ תַּחַת מַדְרֵגָתוֹ, שָׁפָל מִמַּה שֶּׁהוּא
> וְעַל כָּל פָּנִים, "אֶל יָצָא אִישׁ מִמְּקוֹמוֹ", הַיְנוּ לְמַעְלָה מִמַּדְרֵגָתוֹ
> כְּגוֹן 'עוֹשֶׂה מַעֲשֶׂה זִמְרִי וּמְבַקֵּשׁ שָׂכָר כְּפִינְחָס'
> וְאֵימָתַי יָכוֹל לִרְאוֹת שִׁפְלוּתוֹ בְּשַׁבָּת ?
> כְּשֶׁעוֹשֶׂה **תְּשׁוּבָה שְׁלֵמָה**, שֶׁהִיא שַׁבָּת
> כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתוּב: "וְשַׁבְתָּ עַד ה' אֱלקֶיך, אַתְוָן דְּדֵין כְּאַתְוָן דְּדֵין"
> כִּי יֵשׁ שְׁנֵי תְּשׁוּבוֹת
> אַחַת, יֵשׁ בְּנֵי אָדָם שֶׁעוֹשִׂין מַשָּׂא וּמַתָּן וְהוֹלְכִין בְּהַבְלֵי עוֹלָם הַזֶּה
> וּבְאֶמְצָעוּת נוֹפֵל לוֹ הִרְהוּרֵי תְּשׁוּבָה
> וְאַחַר כָּך חוֹזֵר לִמְקוֹמוֹ הָרִאשׁוֹן
> "הַחַיּוֹת רָצוֹא וָשׁוֹב"
> שֶׁאֵין לוֹ נַיְחָא, כִּי פַּעַם טָמֵא וּפַעַם טָהוֹר כָּשֵׁר וּפָסוּל, אָסוּר וּמֻתָּר
> וְזֶהוּ בְּחִינוֹת שֵׁשֶׁת יְמֵי חוֹל
> אֲבָל **תְּשׁוּבָה שְׁלֵמָה** הוּא בְּחִינוֹת שַׁבָּת, שֶׁיֵּשׁ לוֹ נַיְחָא
> כִּי 'בָּא שַׁבָּת בָּא מְנוּחָה' שֶׁיֵּשׁ לוֹ מְנוּחָה מִכּל וָכל, וְנִדְחֶה הָרַע לְגַמְרֵי
> וְתֵדַע נֶאֱמָנָה, **שֶׁתְּשׁוּבָה שְׁלֵמָה** הוּא בְּחִינוֹת שַׁבָּת
> כִּי אִיתָא בְּמִדְרָשׁ רַבָּה
> כְּשֶׁפָּגַע אָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן לְקַיִן, וְשָׁאַל לוֹ מַה נַּעֲשָׂה בְּדִינְך
> וְהֵשִׁיב לוֹ שֶׁעָשָׂה תְּשׁוּבָה
> אָמַר, אִם כָּך תַּקִּיף חֵילָא דִּתְשׁוּבָה, פָּתַח וְאָמַר "מִזְמוֹר שִׁיר לְיוֹם הַשַּׁבָּת"
> וְלִכְאוֹרָה, מָה עִנְיַן שַׁבָּת אֵצֶל תְּשׁוּבָה
> אֲבָל לְפִי דְּבָרֵינוּ מְכֻוָּן הֵיטֵב
> כִּי כְּשֶׁעוֹשֶׂה **תְּשׁוּבָה שְׁלֵמָה** וְנִדְחֶה הָרָע לְגַמְרֵי, וְיֵשׁ לוֹ נַיְחָא
> זֶהוּ בְּחִינוֹת שַׁבָּת, וּבְחִינַת שַׁדַּי, וּבְחִינַת מט"ט
> כִּי 'מַה הוּא שַׁדַּי, שֶׁאָמַר לְעוֹלָמוֹ דַּי'
> וּבְחִינוֹת שַׁבָּת גַּם כֵּן כָּך כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתוּב: "וַיִּשְׁבּת בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי מִכָּל מְלַאכְתּוֹ", וְאָמַר דַּי
> וּבְחִינוֹת מט"ט, הוּא גַּם כֵּן בְּחִינוֹת שַׁדַּי כַּנּוֹדַע
> עַל פָּסוּק "וַיִּקַח אֶת הָאָדָם וַיַּנִּיחֵהוּ בְגַן עֵדֶן" וְכוּ'
> 'וַיִּקַח' מֵאָן נְטַל לֵהּ ? אֶלָּא נְטַל לֵהּ מֵאַרְבַּע יְסוֹדִין דִּילֵהּ וְכוּ'
> בְּזִמְנָא דְּתָב בִּתְיוּבְתָּא וּמִתְעֲסִק בְּאוֹרַיְתָא
> קֻדְשָׁא בְּרִיך הוּא נְטַל לֵהּ מִתַּמָּן
> אִתְמַר "וּמִשָּׁם יִפָּרֵד" אַפְרִישׁ נַפְשֵׁהּ מִתַּאֲוָה דִּילְהוֹן וְכוּ'
> לְעָבְדָהּ בְּפִקּוּדִין דַּעֲשֵׂה, וּלְשָׁמְרָהּ בְּפִקּוּדִין דְּלא תַעֲשֶׂה וְכוּ'
> וְאִי עָבַר עַל אוֹרַיְתָא, אִתְשַׁקְיָה מִמְּרִירוּ דְּאִילָנָא
> רָע, דְּאִיהוּ יֵצֶר הָרָע
> וְאִם תָּיְבִין בִּתְיוּבְתָּא
> אִתְמַר בְּהוֹן "וַיּוֹרֵהוּ ה' עֵץ", דָּא עֵץ הַחַיִּים
> וּבֵהּ "וַיִּמְתְּקוּ הַמָּיִם"
> וְדָא משֶׁה מָשִׁיחַ דְּאִתְמַר בֵּהּ "וּמַטֵּה הָאֱלהִים בְּיָדִי"
> מַטֶּה דָּא מְט"ט, מִסִּטְרֵהּ חַיִּים וּמִסִּטְרֵהּ מִיתָה
> עַד כָּאן לְשׁוֹנוֹ
> וְזֶה כְּמוֹ שֶׁפֵּרַשְׁנוּ
> הַיְנוּ כְּשֶׁעוֹשֶׂה תְּשׁוּבָה שְׁלֵמָה
> שֶׁיִּדְחֶה הָרָע לְגַמְרֵי וְנַעֲשֶׂה כֻּלּוֹ טוֹב
> זֶהוּ בְּחִינוֹת משֶׁה מָשִׁיחַ, דְּאִתְמַר בֵּהּ "וּמַטֵּה הָאֱלהִים בְּיָדִי"
> הַיְנוּ שֶׁהָיָה בְּיָדוֹ לַהֲפך [מֵרַע לְטוֹב]
> וּמַטֵּה דָּא מְט"ט, מִסִּטְרֵהּ חַיִּים וּמִסִּטְרֵהּ מִיתָה
> כִּי מט"ט הוּא בְּחִינוֹת מִשְׁנָה, שֶׁזֶּהוּ בְּחִינוֹת שֵׁשֶׁת יְמֵי הַחֹל
> שֶׁהֵם בְּחִינוֹת שִׁשָּׁה סִדְרֵי מִשְׁנֶה
> שֶׁכְּלוּלִים מִשִּׁשָּׁה בְּחִינוֹת כָּשֵׁר וּפָסוּל טָמֵא וְטָהוֹר אָסוּר וּמֻתָּר כַּנּוֹדַע
> וְעַל כֵּן אֵלּוּ בְּנֵי אָדָם שֶׁאֵינָם קְבוּעִים עֲדַיִן בַּעֲבוֹדַת הַבּוֹרֵא יִתְבָּרַך
> וְאֵין **תְּשׁוּבָתָם שְׁלֵמָה** עֲדַיִן
> רַק לִפְעָמִים נוֹפֵל לוֹ הִרְהוּר תְּשׁוּבָה וּמַתְחִיל קְצָת בַּעֲבוֹדָתוֹ יִתְבָּרַך
> וְאַחַר כָּך נוֹפֵל מִזֶּה וְחוֹזֵר לִמְקוֹמוֹ
> וְאַחַר כָּך הוּא חוֹזֵר וְנִתְעוֹרֵר
> וְחוֹזֵר וְנוֹפֵל וְכֵן מִשְׁתַּנֶּה בְּכָל פַּעַם מִטּוֹב לְרַע וּמֵרַע לְטוֹב
> זאת הַתְּשׁוּבָה הִיא בְּחִינוֹת שֵׁשֶׁת יְמֵי הַחֹל
> שֶׁהֵם בְּחִינוֹת כָּשֵׁר וּפָסוּל וְכוּ' כַּנַּ"ל
> כִּי הוּא גַּם כֵּן פַּעַם כָּשֵׁר וּפַעַם פָּסוּל, פַּעַם טָמֵא וּפַעַם טָהוֹר וְכוּ'
> כִּי אֵין לוֹ נַיְחָא
> אֲבָל כְּשֶׁעוֹשֶׂה **תְּשׁוּבָה שְׁלֵמָה**, זֶהוּ בְּחִינוֹת שַׁבָּת, כְּמוֹ שֶׁפֵּרַשְׁנוּ
> וְזֶהוּ בְּחִינַת משֶׁה מָשִׁיחַ
> שֶׁהָיָה בְּיָדוֹ לַהֲפך מֵרַע לְטוֹב, וְנִדְחֶה הָרַע לְגַמְרֵי
> וְזֶהוּ בְּחִינוֹת שַׁדַּי, וְיֵשׁ לוֹ נַיְחָא מִכּל וָכל
> וּבְחִינַת מט"ט גַּם כֵּן בְּחִינוֹת שַׁדַּי
> אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאָמַרְנוּ שֶׁבְּחִינוֹת מט"ט הוּא מִשְׁנָה
> זֶהוּ בְּשֵׁשֶׁת יְמֵי הַחֹל
> אֲבָל כְּשֶׁבָּא שַׁבָּת בָּא מְנוּחָה, "וַיִּשְׁבּת מִכָּל מְלַאכְתּוֹ"
> וְזֶהוּ בְּחִינַת שַׁדַּי [אֲזַי נִכְלָל מט"ט בִּבְחִינַת שַׁדַּ"י]
> הַיּוֹצֵא לָנוּ מִזֶּה
> שֶׁכְּשֶׁעוֹשֶׂה *תְּשׁוּבָה שְׁלֵמָה* שֶׁהוּא בְּחִינַת שַׁבָּת כְּמוֹ שֶׁאָמַרְנוּ
> עַל יְדֵי זֶה יָכוֹל לִרְאוֹת שִׁפְלוּתוֹ כַּנַּ"ל
> וְזֶה הוּא בְּטַח בַּה'
> לְשׁוֹן הַשְׁקֵט וָבֶטַח, שֶׁיֵּשׁ לוֹ מְנוּחָה מִכּל וָכל
> וַעֲשֵׂה טוֹב, הַיְנוּ שֶׁנִּתְהַפֵּך מֵרַע לְטוֹב גָּמוּר
> שְׁכָן אֶרֶץ, הַיְנוּ בְּחִינוֹת נֶפֶשׁ, כְּמָה דְּאַתְּ אָמַר "נַפְשִׁי כְּאֶרֶץ" וְכוּ'
> הַיְנוּ שֶׁהַנֶּפֶשׁ יֵשׁ לוֹ נַיְחָא, מֵחֲמַת שֶׁעָשָׂה **תְּשׁוּבָה שְׁלֵמָה** כַּנַּ"ל
> וּכְשֶׁעוֹשֶׂה **תְּשׁוּבָה שְׁלֵמָה** הוּא בְּחִינוֹת שַׁבָּת, וְיָכוֹל לִרְאוֹת שִׁפְלוּתוֹ, וַחֲשִׁיבוּת וּגְדֻלּוֹת יִשְׂרָאֵל
> וּרְעֵה אֱמוּנָה, הַיְנוּ שֶׁיָּכוֹל לִהְיוֹת כְּמוֹ רָעֲיָא מְהֵימָנָא
> שֶׁיָּכוֹל לִמְסֹר אֶת נַפְשׁוֹ בְּעַד יִשְׂרָאֵל.
> שַׁיָּך לְעֵיל, לְעִנְיַן שִׁפְלוּת, שֶׁהוּא בְּחִינוֹת "שְׁבוּ אִישׁ תַּחְתָּיו"
> דְּהַיְנוּ שֶׁמַּחֲזִיק עַצְמוֹ שָׁפָל לְמַטָּה תַּחַת מְקוֹמוֹ וּמַדְרֵגָתוֹ
> שׁוּב שָׁמַעְתִּי מִשְּׁמוֹ, זִכְרוֹנוֹ לִבְרָכָה, בְּעִנְיָן זֶה
> שֶׁעַל יְדֵי זֶה שֶׁזּוֹכִין לִרְאוֹת שִׁפְלוּתוֹ בֶּאֱמֶת
> עַל יְדֵי זֶה אֵין שׁוּם אָדָם יָכוֹל לְהוֹצִיאוֹ וְלִדְחוֹתוֹ מִמְּקוֹמוֹ
> דְּהַיְנוּ לְקַפֵּחַ פַּרְנָסָתוֹ, חַס וְשָׁלוֹם
> כִּי מֵאַחַר שֶׁהוּא עָנָו וְשָׁפָל בֶּאֱמֶת
> הוּא בִּבְחִינַת אַיִן, וְאֵינוֹ תַּחַת הַמָּקוֹם כְּלָל
> עַל כֵּן בְּוַדַּאי אֵין יְכוֹלִין לִדְחוֹתוֹ מִמְּקוֹמוֹ
> וְזֶהוּ: "שְׁבוּ אִישׁ תַּחְתָּיו אַל יֵצֵא אִישׁ מִמְּקוֹמוֹ"
> הַיְנוּ עַל יְדֵי שֶׁזּוֹכִין לְשִׁפְלוּת, שֶׁזֶּהוּ בְּחִינוֹת "שְׁבוּ אִישׁ תַּחְתָּיו"
> שֶׁמַּחֲזִיק עַצְמוֹ תָּמִיד בְּשִׁפְלוּת לְמַטָּה תַּחַת מְקוֹמוֹ וּמַדְרֵגָתוֹ כַּנַּ"ל
> עַל יְדֵי זֶה "אַל יֵצֵא אִישׁ מִמְּקוֹמוֹ"
> כִּי שׁוּם אָדָם לא יוּכַל לְהוֹצִיאוֹ מִמְּקוֹמוֹ
> דְּהַיְנוּ לִדְחוֹתוֹ מִפַּרְנָסָתוֹ, חַס וְשָׁלוֹם כַּנַּ"ל
> וְזֶה שֶׁאָמְרוּ רַבּוֹתֵינוּ, זִכְרוֹנָם לִבְרָכָה: 'כָּל הַיּוֹרֵד לְאֻמָּנוּת חֲבֵרוֹ כְּאִלּוּ בָּא עַל אֵשֶׁת אִישׁ' וְכוּ'
> כִּי מֵאַחַר שֶׁיּוֹרֵד לְאֻמָּנוּת חֲבֵרוֹ
> וְרוֹצֶה לִדְחוֹת חֲבֵרוֹ מִמְּקוֹמוֹ וּמִפַּרְנָסָתוֹ
> נִמְצָא שֶׁהוּא רוֹצֶה לִפְגּם בְּחִינַת שִׁפְלוּת הַנַּ"ל
> בְּחִינַת: "שְׁבוּ אִישׁ תַּחְתָּיו" וְכוּ' כַּנַּ"ל
> וְעַל כֵּן הוּא 'כְּאִלּוּ בָּא עַל אֵשֶׁת אִישׁ'
> כִּי אֵשֶׁת רָאשֵׁי תֵבוֹת שְׁבוּ אִישׁ תַּחְתָּיו
> הַיְנוּ שֶׁפּוֹגֵם בִּבְחִינַת עֲנָוָוה וְשִׁפְלוּת
> שֶׁהוּא בְּחִינַת 'שְׁבוּ אִישׁ תַּחְתָּיו'
> שֶׁעַל יְדֵי זֶה 'אַל יֵצֵא אִישׁ מִמְּקוֹמוֹ' כַּנַּ"ל

Comment: re how to achieve it, there is an list of short points found here, Sefer haMidot - Teshuvah: http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Sefer_Hamidot#%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94_REPENTANCE:

Answer (score 0):

> How does one return to his original self; what does this even mean?
> And how does this helps a person not to do a sin anymore in the
> future; wasn't it from this state of being that one sinned in the
> first place?

True *teshuvah* means you can create a self which is what you would have been had you kept the Torah since you were born. Your actual self (which sinned) then becomes sublimated to the new self.

From this perspective, someone who is a *ba'al teshuvah* is equivalent to someone who was always a "*tzaddik*".

That is why at the *simchas beis ha'shoeva* we [find](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%A0%D7%92_%D7%90) that both are equal in the end:

> ת"ר יש מהן אומרים אשרי ילדותנו שלא ביישה את זקנותנו אלו חסידים ואנשי
> מעשה ויש מהן אומרים אשרי זקנותנו שכפרה את ילדותנו אלו בעלי תשובה
>
> Our rabbis have taught: Some sang, "Happy is our youth that did not
> embarrass our old age," these are the perfectly righteous and men of
> great deeds. Others sang, "Happy is our old age that atoned for our
> youth."

Answer (score -1):

You ask, "But how does one achieve this? How does one return to his original self; what does this even mean?".

The Alter Rebbe in his [Igeret HaTeshuva (chapter 7)](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/1029240/jewish/Chapter-7.htm) explains that "cleansing your soul", and thus returning to the state your soul originally is in, is a two-step process.

The first step is:

> In the true and direct path to the lower teshuvah, returning the
> latter hai noted above, there are two general elements. **The first is
> to awaken supreme compassion from the source of mercy for his spirit
> (neshama) and divine soul (nefesh) that has fallen from a lofty pea**k,
> the true Life, into a deep pit, the chambers of defilement and sitra
> achra. Divine compassion is also to be aroused for the source of the
> soul in the source of life, the Name of G‑d, the Tetragrammaton. "He
> shall return to G‑d and He will grant him mercy." "Him" would refer to
> G‑d here, arousing mercies on the life-giving power issuing from His
> Name, that has descended into the chambers of the impure sitra achra,
> to give them vitality. This was brought about through the deeds of
> man, his scheming and evil thoughts.

The second step is:

> The second element is **to crush and subdue evil, the husk and sitra
> achra**, whose entire being is simply grossness and arrogance. "If you
> exalt yourself like the eagle..." This crushing and subjugation is to
> be literally into the ground, for this is its death and nullification.
> Evil is crushed through a broken and shattered heart, a sense of
> personal unworthiness, repugnance ...

How is the second step done?

> But the true humbling of the heart, that it be broken and crushed, and the removal of the spirit of impurity and sitra achra, is achieved through being a "master of accounting" with all the profundity of the mind. He must concentrate his intellect and understanding deeply for a period every day, or at night before Tikun Chatzot, to realise that through his sins he wrought the exile of the Shechinah, as noted above. **He will also ponder that he [caused] the uprooting of his spirit and divine soul from the true Life, and demeaned it to a place of defilement and death**, the chambers of the sitra achra. He must become deeply aware that his soul has become a vehicle for them, receiving from them vitality to endow his body, as noted above.

In [Chapter 8 of Igeret HaTeshuva](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/1029244/jewish/Chapter-8.htm), the Alter Rebbe discusses what happens when the "cleansing spirit passes over and purifies a person":

> As there is a "restoration" of the hai above, so too below in the divine soul within man, no more do "your sins divide." It is said, "He cleanses"— those who come back to Him, to lave and cleanse their souls of the soiled garments, the "externals" that the Talmud describes as "encrusting ..."
>
> After the cleansing spirit passes over and purifies them, then their
> souls are enabled to return unto G‑d Himself, literally, to ascend the
> greatest heights, to their very source, and cleave to Him with a
> remarkable unity. This is the original unity, the ultimate in union,
> that existed before the soul was blown by the breath of His mouth to
> descend and be incorporated within the body of man. (To illustrate
> this unity: before one exhales, the breath is united with the person;
> he and his breath are not separable yet.) This is the perfect return,
> teshuvah. This state of unity and this return are called teshuvah
> ila'a, the superior return, that follows teshuvah tata'a, the inferior
> return. The Zohar, in Raya Mehemna on Nasso, explains that teshuvah
> ilaa is being occupied with Torah study, in reverence and fear of the
> Holy One ... for this is ben yud-hai or binah ... (Here the
> superiority of the penitent over the perfectly saintly, as the Zohar
> states in Chayei Sara, is that "They draw onto themselves with a more
> intense longing of the heart, and with greater forcefulness, to
> approach the King...")

Comment: It would help me if someone downvotes, to explain why...